# MYSQL - Select elements where value equal to any

Tags: php, mysql

Imagine a simple query, where `$value` is a boolean variable:

```
"SELECT * FROM table where table.value = {$value}";
```

It's easy to filter the selection for `$value` equal to `true` or equal to `false`.

The question is: how could I filter by ANY (`true` or `false`) in the same query?

Comment: Just remove the `where` condition or use `OR` operator.

Comment: Is your `$value` will always be as you've described? Or it will be non-boolean list (and non-boolean field) ?

Comment: i think no good idea in SQL level, maybe use another SQL without where and judge in PHP level

Comment: I guess, this link could help you. [Subqueries with ANY, IN, or SOME](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/any-in-some-subqueries.html)

Comment: @AlmaDo - I can control `$value` value. I'm looking for a way to get all values with the same query. I thought there may be a wildcard to achieve it...

Comment: @ManoloSalsas well, you can act like this way (I've added explanations)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Sets of values and comparison**

There's a field of some data type which can take some set of values (`ENUM` is very good example, but not only example). So if you want to compare by some **subset** of values, you can use [`IN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in):

```
SELECT * FROM t WHERE v IN ($values)
```

here `$values` stands for *set* of values, not one value. Set of values is delimited by comma, thus, if you have array:

```
$values = [1, 2, 5];
```

then you need to query like:

```
//values escaping is needed, but out of this issue:
$query = 'SELECT * FROM t WHERE v IN ('.join(',', $values).')';
```

Also, string literals have to be enclosed by quotes - therefore, construction above should be modified for them like:

```
$values = ['foo', 'bar'];
$inSet  = array_map(function($x)
{
   return '"'.$x.'"';
}, $values);
$query = 'SELECT * FROM t WHERE v IN ('.join(',', $inSet).')';
```

**Current case**

There is, however, one case when comparison above won't be needed. It's like your question. In your case, your data type full set is equal to subset of values in comparison. Thus, whole condition makes no sense - because data type can not hold anything out of it's full set of values. Thus, you can either omit your condition at all or leave `WHERE 1` (if having `WHERE` is mandatory).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM tablе;
SELECT * FROM table where value = 0 OR value = 1;
SELECT * FROM table where (value = 0 OR value = 1) -- AND (other where conditions); (remove -- to uncomment)
```

Comment: I think he wants sth in one sql ~_~

Comment: These are only various examples.